# Difference between getResources().getColor(R.color.Black) and directly R.color.Black

Tags: android, colors

i noticed a strange behavior of eclipse?

I I have a static variable:

```
public static colorID = R.color.Black;
```

Sometimes it matches with R.color.Black:

```
if(colorID == R.color.Black)
     //sometimes it works
```

sometimes i Need to use

```
if(colorID == getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
```

It's really annoying to find the fault by testing if your code is big...

So i want to know why it sometimes work why not, and why the returning integer is sometimes different and sometimes not. They are both referencing to R.color.Black in my custom `color.xml` file in my `values` Folder. So why they are different sometimes?

Comment: Add the `final` keyword: `public static final colorID = R.color.Black;`. My guess is that you will find that you are assigning `colorID` a value in multiple places, with differing values.

Comment: Note that `getColor()` returns a color value, not a color id. If it matches like that, you have a bug somewhere that mixes values and ids.

Comment: @CommonsWare I had the same thought. But i'm always assigning directly with `R.Color....`. That should be okay? Even if i assign them from "different places"?

Comment: @laalto ah okay, i understand! i will walk through my code !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getColor returns the actual AARRGGBB color value.  R.color.Black is an id that holds a color, which may or may not be black.  One is the actual value, one is a reference to the color.